# Is there a flip animation available to use when transitioning between activities?

Tags: android, animation, android-2.1-eclair

When transitioning between activities, such as calling `startActivity();` or when using the `back` button, the screen slides in from the sides.

Is there any way to alter this? I have a flash-card like application, so when I move from activity A to activity B I would like the screen to flip over like turning a real flash card.

Is there any way to do this out of the box? Or does this require some custom animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the applications have no control over the transitions between their activities.

What you *could* do is merge the two activities using a custom ViewGroup that changes between the two Views using any animation you like. It's not trivial but should certainly be doable.

Answer (score 7):

Since Android 2.0 (API Level 5), you can use `Activity.overridePendingTransition` specify an explicit transition animation .

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)